# Helm 3 installing charts that are not enabled

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have an umbrella chart with some other charts in it. The problem is, there is a particular chart that is being installed even if it's installed.
Here is the `chart.yaml` for the umbrella chart

```
    - name: casa
      condtion: persistence.configmap.gluuCasaEnabled
      version: 1.0.0
```

Here is the `persistence` block part.

```
 persistence:
  configmap: 
    # Auto install other services. If enabled the respective service chart will be installed
    gluuCasaEnabled: false  
    gluuPassportEnabled: false
```

And here is the casa service `chart.yaml`

```
apiVersion: v1
appVersion: "4.0.0_01"
description: A Helm chart for casa
name: casa
version: 1.0.0
maintainers:
- name: Gluu
home: https://www.gluu.org/ee
email: support@gluu.org
```

Here is how the dicrectories look like or the services

```
├── Chart.yaml
├── README.md
├── charts
│   ├── casa
│   │   ├── Chart.yaml
│   │   ├── templates
│   │   │   ├── _helpers.tpl
│   │   │   ├── configmap.yaml
│   │   │   ├── deployment.yaml
│   │   │   ├── jobs.yaml
│   │   │   ├── pvc.yaml
│   │   │   ├── secrets.yaml
│   │   │   ├── service.yaml
│   │   │   └── storageclass.yaml
│   │   └── values.yaml
│   ├── config
│   │   ├── Chart.yaml
│   │   ├── README.md
│   │   ├── templates
│   │   │   ├── _helpers.tpl
│   │   │   ├── configmaps.yaml
│   │   │   └── load-init-config.yml
│   │   ├── tls_generator.py
│   │   └── values.yaml
```

Funny thing is, others are working as expected when disabled or enabled.

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had a typo in `condition` block of the dependencies